# Writing anonymous function is giving error

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I am trying to compare 'named function' to 'anonymous function' but in a simple propgram I am getting error. I am doing everything right, don't know why error is coming. Can someone help?

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>

//named Fn
function alpha(){
  alert('hi');
}

//Anonymous Fn
function(){
  alert('hello');
}

//IIFE
(function (){
  alert('good day');
})();

alpha(); 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect 'good day' and 'hi' to be alerted but instead getting error.

> Note: I read anonymous function is one without a name so wrote the
>   second function without name. Please, someone paste correct snippet as
>   I don't know why this is wrong

```
 function(){ <------------------- A function without name.
```

Comment: `I am doing everything right`... obviously not.

Comment: but I have not missed any bracket. Please tell what to do?

Comment: Please, can someone help me out pasting correct snippet. I am not missing any brackets.

Comment: `function(){` `<---` set a name to that function.

Comment: you cannot have an anonymous function in the root like that

Comment: This is the anonymous function (function(){ ... });

Comment: hi @GetOffMyLawn: Please help out writing anonymous function correctly. ;(

Comment: Do it exactly like the function below it

Comment: @Deadpool You're getting an error because you aren't naming your function. Anonymous functions are only appropriate in certain situations. Check out my different code snippets below. I think that will clear things up for you. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really declare an anonymous function. You need to use it when something calls for it. you have:

```
function(){
  alert('hello');
}
```

That's going to always throw an error since you haven't named it. If you attached it to something where an anonymous function is appropriate you'd be fine. such as:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  alert('hello');
}, 500);
```

So you're modified and working code snippet would look like this:

```js
//named Fn
function alpha(){
  alert('hi');
}

//Anonymous Fn
setTimeout(function(){
  alert('hello');
}, 500);

//IIFE
(function (){
  alert('good day');
})();

alpha();
```

You could also just make it an IIFE like this:

```js
//named Fn
function alpha(){
  alert('hi');
}

//Anonymous Fn
(function(){
  alert('hello');
})();

//IIFE
(function (){
  alert('good day');
})();

alpha();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only write an anonymous function like your `hello` as an *expression* - that is, in a place where the interpreter would expect a *value*, such as inside of parentheses, as an argument to another function. Otherwise, the interpreter tries to parse it as a function *declaration* (whose function name gets hoisted as a `var`) - but without a name, it's impossible, because there's nothing to extract as a name, hoist as a variable, and assign to.

The solution is to just put the anonymous function inside of parentheses:

```js
//named Fn
function alpha(){
  alert('hi');
}

//Anonymous Fn
(function(){
  alert('hello');
});

//IIFE
(function (){
  alert('good day');
})();

alpha();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can copy-paste the javascript code into your browser's console (developer tools).

On Firefox, you will get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: function statement requires a name [Learn More]
```

By clicking on [Learn More], you will be directed to the [relevant documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unnamed_function_statement?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=firefox-console-errors&utm_campaign=default).

> A function statement (or function declaration) requires a name, this
>   won't work:
>
> ```
> function () {
>     return 'Hello world';
> } // SyntaxError: function statement requires a name
> ```
>
> You can use a function expression (assignment) instead:
>
> ```
> var greet = function() {
>     return 'Hello world';
> };
> ```